# Facebook showing several images when sharing URL as my page but not as myself. Why?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

When I share a URL from my “page” on Facebook, it attaches several images to the Facebook post. All the ones in the blog post, the site logo, etc. And it doesn't show a summary of the blog post either (see screenshots).

When I share the exact same URL as myself on Facebook (and this is the way I want to look), it only attaches 1 image and the summary of the post.

[image: This is how I do not want to look]

As you can see, several photos are attached, and the arrows on the sides shows you can see them all.

And here it looks like a normal posting, as it should be.

[image]

I've tried to delete them, repost, delete again, repost again, but the same thing still happens. What can I do to fix this? Any ideas?