# Post as Facebook Page a page preview without image preview

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

When I'm sharing an URL as "me", posting on in "Home" section, I can clearly see two "x" buttons -- first in top-right corner of an image and second one in top-right corner of page preview box (i.e. the one with title and intro text). When I click first one, image preview disappears, page preview remains.

This allows me to post page without image preview, if it is wrong or other way unwanted. Cool!

When I'm sharing *exactly the same* URL posting as one of my pages (directly on that Facebook Page main screen) I can only see one "x" button -- the one over image (i.e. there is not "x" button over page preview) -- and when clicking it, *entire preview* (both image and page preview) disappears.

This forces me to choose: either page preview with wrong image preview or no preview at all. Wrong.

Anyone got any idea / information, what causes this difference, when posting exactly the same URL as Facebook Page and as a regular user?

Is there any workaround to this problem -- i.e. is there any tool in Facebook, trick or solution, that would allow me to post URL with regular page preview, but without image preview in the same time?

<sub>*Note: This problem is somewhat opposite to [this one](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/90962/21486).*</sub>